# How to remove multiple columns that end with same text in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to remove
 a group of columns from a dataset. All of the variables to remove end with the text "prefix".

I did manage to "collect' them into a group using the following:
[image]

and then tried a series of ways to drop that group that resulted in a variety of errors. Can anyone please, propose a way to remove these columns?

Comment: Please dont post png for code... post the code and highlight with '()'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
df2 = df.drop([col for col in df.columns if 'prefix' in col],axis=1)
```

Comment: do you know, should this code work with pyspark dataframes as well? I am trying to do the same code and get TypeError: drop() got an unexpected keyword argument 'axis'

Answer (score 7):

```
df2 = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('prefix')]
```

Comment: I like this variant

Answer (score 6):

for the sake of completeness:

```
In [306]: df
Out[306]:
   prefixcol1  col2prefix  col3prefix  colN
0           1           1           1     1
1           2           2           2     2
2           3           3           3     3

In [307]: df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('prefix$')]
Out[307]:
   prefixcol1  colN
0           1     1
1           2     2
2           3     3
```

or another variant:

```
In [388]: df.select(lambda x: re.search(r'prefix$', str(x)) is None, axis=1)
Out[388]:
   prefixcol1  colN
0           1     1
1           2     2
2           3     3
```

Answer (score 5):

using `filter` and `regex`

```
df.filter(regex=r'^((?!prefix).)*$')
```

#### Demo

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(2, 6),
                  columns=['oneprefix', 'one',
                           'twoprefix', 'two',
                           'threeprefix', 'three'])

df.filter(regex=r'^((?!prefix).)*$')
```

[image]

where:

```
df
```

[image]

---

#### Timing

All are about the same
[image]

Comment: I like this one even more. I was working on it, but you were faster. Here is my variant: `df.filter(regex=r'^(.(?!prefix))*$')`

Comment: I think your RegEx will not work for columns containing word `prefix` at the beginning, like `prefix_col`

Comment: It is very unlikely that someone would get so many columns that the difference becomes important but I think endswith scales better. :)

Comment: @ayhan, yes, the performance is not important in this case, but RegEx's are much more powerful in terms of filtering - just my 2 cents...

Comment: @MaxU Sure, str methods are for very basic filtering and they may become inadaquate for many cases.

Answer (score 4):

I think you need:

```
not_prefix_cols= [col for col in df.columns if not 'prefix' in col]
df2[not_prefix_cols]
```

But better is use:

```
prefix_cols= [col for col in df.columns if not col.endswith('prefix')]
print (df[prefix_cols])
```

Sample:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'prefixone' : pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4]),
                   'twoprefix' : pd.Series([20, 30, 40, 50]),
                   'two1prefix' : pd.Series([20, 30, 40, 50])})

print (df)
   prefixone  two1prefix  twoprefix
0          1          20         20
1          2          30         30
2          3          40         40
3          4          50         50

prefix_cols= [col for col in df.columns if not col.endswith('prefix')]
print (df[prefix_cols])
   prefixone
0          1
1          2
2          3
3          4
```