# Delete data frame column if column name ends with some string, Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe with below columns:

```
SectorName', 'Sector', 'ItemName', 'Item', 'Counterpart SectorName', 'Counterpart Sector', 'Stocks and TransactionsName', 'Stocks and Transactions', 'Units', 'Scale', 'Frequency', 'Date', 'Value'
```

How to delete column from `df` where column name ends with `Name`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove multiple columns that end with same text in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38426168/1278112)

Answer (score 15):

You can filter by inverting (~) boolean mask for columns which **not** need delete with [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and [`str.endswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.endswith.html), also working [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with `$` for match end of string:

```
cols = ['SectorName', 'Name Sector', 'ItemName', 'Item', 'Counterpart SectorName']
df = pd.DataFrame([range(5)], columns = cols)
print (df)
   SectorName  Name Sector  ItemName  Item  Counterpart SectorName
0           0            1         2     3                       4

print (~df.columns.str.endswith('Name'))
[False  True False  True False]

df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.endswith('Name')]
```

---

```
df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('Name$')]
```

Or filter columns names first:

```
print (df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('Name')])
Index(['Sector', 'Item'], dtype='object')

df1 = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('Name')]]
```

---

```
print (df1)
   Name Sector  Item
0            1     3
```

Comment: thanks, I go for 2nd one.

Comment: Can we give multiple, like Ends with 'Code', df1 = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.endswith('Name', 'Code')]]

Comment: You need chain conditions like `df1 = df[df.columns[~(df.columns.str.endswith('Name') | df.columns.str.endswith('Code'))]] `

Comment: Or `df1 = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('Name$|Code$')]`

Comment: yes working fine... thanks again...

Comment: the `~` is a `!` (not) so `df[df.columns[~(df.columns.str.endswith('Name') ` will return all the columns that does *not* (`!`) have `'Name'`

Comment: @jezrael, do you know, should the same code work if I am working with a pyspark dataframe instead of a pandas one?